# How to register DLL for COM interop on other machine?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, regasm

I created an ActiveX library in C# with 2 referenced libraries and registered it for COM interop and signed it using a strong name key with Visual Studio. It works fine, but now I want to register it on another computer. I used regasm with /codebase for registering the DLL but when I try to instantiate the ActiveX object the debugger throws an error: Automation server can't create object. I already configured the Internet Explorer to allow initializing controls not marked safe for scripting, but it didn't help.

Comment: One thing to remember is bitness... Make sure you call the right version of regasm on the client, either from Framework64 or in Framework (for x86). Not sure that would be your issue but something to note. Good luck!

Comment: Forgetting to deploy a dependency or hoping that it can be found or forgetting /tlb when necessary would be other failure modes.  Use SysInterals' ProcMon on the machine to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: blins you were right the problem was that I used the wrong regasm on the other machine and that's why it couldn't find the ActiveX object.